# found...object but expected myClass error using a Java Stack

Tags: java, class, object, stack

Compiling error "Incompatible types - found java.lang.Object but expected E" is generated when I attempt to compile code in this form:

```
public class E {
    private int x;       

    public E {
        x = 0;
    }
}

public class Class {
    private E o;
    private E b;
    private Stack stack = new Stack();

    public void foo() {
        stack.push(o);
    }

    public void bar() {
        **b = stack.pop();**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may declare the stack to contain `E`s:

```
private Stack<E> stack = new Stack<E>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try casting to E.

```
public void bar() {
    b = (E)stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Java, is that the proper way to implement?  There is no <E>?  Is this so that the Stack can store multiple types?

Comment: Yes, you can do that as Arne suggests.